# Fill logical matrix with values from list

Tags: r, list, matrix

My question is about filling in values by logical selection. I have a matrix

```
> mymat
               test
sample      1     2     3     4     5
  1sample FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  2sample FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  3sample  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  4sample FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  5sample FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and a list of values

```
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"

[[4]]
[1] "d"

[[5]]
[1] "e"
```

I need to fill in the matrix (or create new data structure) where the element from the nth list is matched to the nth column in the matrix as many times as the row value is TRUE so the resulting data would look like this:

```
> mymat
               test
sample      1   2    3     4     5
  1sample <NA> <NA>  c   <NA> <NA>
  2sample <NA> <NA>  c    d   <NA>
  3sample    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
  4sample <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
  5sample <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `replace`

```
dim<-`(replace(unlist(mylist)[col(mymat)], !mymat, NA), dim(mymat))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] NA   NA   "c"  NA   NA  
#[2,] NA   NA   "c"  "d"  NA  
#[3,] "a"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
#[4,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
#[5,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Or if we need to change the `mymat`

```
mymat[] <- replace(unlist(mylist)[col(mymat)], !mymat, NA)
mymat
#         test
#sample    1   2  3   4   5 
#  1sample NA  NA "c" NA  NA
#  2sample NA  NA "c" "d" NA
#  3sample "a" NA NA  NA  NA
#  4sample NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#  5sample NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: I knew there was a way around with `col(mymat)` ;-) (though I was heading for a more simple one ;-) )

Comment: second option works best as i prefer to keep row names.. thanks @akrun!

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `list` into a `matrix` and replace with the value in the matrix when appropriate.

```
mylist_mat <-  matrix(rep(unlist(mylist), each=nrow(mymat)), ncol=ncol(mymat))
res_mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(mymat), nrow=nrow(mymat))
res_mat[mymat] <- mylist_mat[mymat]
res_mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] NA   NA   "c"  NA   NA  
#[2,] NA   NA   "c"  "d"  NA  
#[3,] "a"  NA   NA   NA   NA  
#[4,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
#[5,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: How are you in my head?? :p The only difference I had was `mylist_mat`.. I used `matrix(unlist(l1), ncol = ncol(df)-1, nrow = nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)` :)

Comment: @Sotos lol but I'm feeling there is a more direct way, trying to find it now ;-) (I had the feeling the first "column" was row.names as it supposed to be a matrix and so only logical :-/)

Comment: Right... that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using matrix indexing is

```
# construct matrix of NAs
myMat2 <- myMat * NA
# fill in letter values
myMat2[myMat] <- unlist(mylist)[myMat * col(myMat)]
```

**data**

```
myMat <- 
structure(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L))
mylist <- as.list(letters[1:5])
```